# How do i get an AngularJS value in a page?

Tags: angularjs

i have limited knowledge with AngualrJS, but need to retrieve some values in a page outputted with AngularJS, how do i retrieve these values with the aim of passing them into Google Tag Manager as variables?

Example:

```
<p data-ng-show="name1">Fare type: <strong>{{value1}}</strong></p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned the values to $scope in the service/factory?

if not then set:

```
$scope.names = name1 (Or whatever you're calling this variable in the service/factory)
```

Then on the html do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be some logic that renders this value in the DOM. Usually it is within a `controller` or `directive`, assigned to a `scope`.

Look in the code for `scope.value1` and you might find where this variable comes from.

Otherwise, if you don't have access to the code and want to hack your way around it, you could try this (assuming the `p` element has an id `#foo`, otherwise get the DOM node in any way you can)

```
angular.element('#foo').scope().value1
```